# Client Object Model access to Custom User Properties

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've setup up a custom user property via central admin and set the value on a couple of my users. That said when I query the User Information List using Query Builder I'm not seeing values for the field. I've even tried specifying the fields to return via ViewFields.

Anyone have any experience with this? Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Casey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've also searched a while, but the closed i came to was [this](http://programmingsharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/07/programmatically-access-user-profile.html)... i ended up using the UserProfileService instead, like described in [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/johnnyt/archive/2010/08/13/getting-sharepoint-s-user-properties-in-your-silverlight-4-application.aspx) article.