# Web Service Select Users Where . . . Query

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm looking for a web service or web service method that supports querying the users store with criteria **against a custom user property**. Something along the lines of (simplified example):

```
Select Users Where FavoriteColor (CustomProperty) Equals "Blue"
```

That returns the users that match the criteria (usernames ideally). I've dug through the documentation for the web services and the UserProfileService and I'm not seeing anything that will meet my current needs. The service will be consumed by a Silverlight application.

I suspect I'm going to have to write a custom web service however thought I'd ask here first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the Client OM?  Here's a link to an article discussing querying users using the Client OM:  http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/22/get-all-users-and-groups-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Does the Client OM allow access to custom user properties? I realize I didn't include that info in my original post. :) Fixing now.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533520/client-object-model-access-to-custom-user-properties  I'm not sure its 100% supported, but there is a possible solution there.

Comment: i don't think its possible via the Client OM, you might aswell write your own web service and deploy it to SharePoint

Comment: Thanks Gents! I ended up writing a simple WCF Service. Thanks again!